# Как сделать select не активным при определенном условии?

Tags: jquery

Есть 2 `select` с опциями:

```
 <select class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="branch">
      <option value="1">Опция 1</option>
      <option value="2">Опция 2</option>
      <option value="3">Опция 3</option>
</select>

 <select class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="test">
      <option value="1">Тест 1</option>
      <option value="2">Тест 2</option>
      <option value="3">Тест 3</option>
</select>
```

Как с помощью jQuery скрыть полностью `select` с `name="test"`, если, к примеру, в первом селекте выбрана только Опция 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
    $("#sel1").change(function() {
        var s = $("#sel1").val(); // Получаем значение выбранного селекта с id sel1
        if (s == '3'){ // Если значение равно 3, то
            $("#sel2").hide(); // Скрываем селект с id sel2
        } else {
            $("#sel2").show();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="branch" id="sel1">
    <option value="1">Опция 1</option>
    <option value="2">Опция 2</option>
    <option value="3">Опция 3</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="test" id="sel2">
    <option value="1">Тест 1</option>
    <option value="2">Тест 2</option>
    <option value="3">Тест 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение !!!

Comment: @Sevastopol` Как я понимаю, автору был необходим сам принцип работы, но спасибо за замечание, добавил.

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант. Код был взят у @Denis640Kb и доработан до логического завершения.

```js
$("#select__branch").change(function() {
  var select = $("#select__branch").val();
  if (select == '3') {
    $("#select__test").hide();
  } else {
    $("#select__test").show();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select__branch" class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="branch">
  <option value="1">Опция 1</option>
  <option value="2">Опция 2</option>
  <option value="3">Опция 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select__test" class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="test">
  <option value="1">Тест 1</option>
  <option value="2">Тест 2</option>
  <option value="3">Тест 3</option>
</select>
```

Второй вариант. Здесь мы `select` не прячем полностью, а просто отключаем.

```js
$("#select__branch").change(function() {
  select_value = $(this).val();
  if (select_value == '3') {
    $("#select__test").prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $("#select__test").prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select__branch" class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="branch">
  <option value="1">Опция 1</option>
  <option value="2">Опция 2</option>
  <option value="3">Опция 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select__test" class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="test">
  <option value="1">Тест 1</option>
  <option value="2">Тест 2</option>
  <option value="3">Тест 3</option>
</select>
```

Третий вариант. Выборка по `id`.

```js
$("#select__branch").on('change', function(i) {
  if ($("option:selected", this).attr('id') == 'disabled') {
    $("#select__test").hide();
  } else {
    $("#select__test").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select__branch" class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="branch">
  <option value="1">Опция 1</option>
  <option value="2">Опция 2</option>
  <option value="3" id="disabled">Опция 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select__test" class="form-control" data-toggle="select" name="test">
  <option value="1">Тест 1</option>
  <option value="2">Тест 2</option>
  <option value="3">Тест 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ` правка отправляется автору ответа на подтверждение изменений. Я всегда за конструктивную критику и совершенно не против изменений, если логика остаётся та же, а исправляются недочёты.

Comment: ` Прошу прощения, хотел просто для проверки. Вы были правы. Оказывается после 2 тыс. меняется сразу без подтверждения.